# Difficulty Understanding Event Sourcing Microservice Event Receiving/Communication

Tags: microservices, domain-driven-design, cqrs, event-sourcing, eventstoredb

I've been aware of event sourcing, CQRS, DDD and micro services for a little while and I'm now at that point where I want to try and start implementing stuff and giving something a go.

I've been looking into the technical side of CQRS and I understand the DDD concepts in there. How both the write side handles commands from the UI and publishes events from it, and how the read side handles events and creates projections on them.

The difficulty I'm having is the communication & a handling events from service-to-service (both from a write to read service and between micro services).

So I want to focus on eventstore (this one: https://eventstore.com/ to be less ambiguous). This is what I want to use as I understand it is a perfect for event sourcing and the simple nature of storing the events means I can use this for a message bus as well.

So my issue falls into two questions:

1. Between the write and the read, in order for the read side to receive/fetch the events created from the write side, am i right in thinking something like a catch up subscription can be used to subscribe to a stream to receive any events written to it or do i use something like polling to fetch events from a given point?
2. Between micro services, I am having an even harder time... So when looking at CQRS tutorials/talks etc... they always seem to talk with an example of an isolated service which receives commands from the UI/API. This is fine. I understand the write side will have an API attached to it so the user can interact with it to perform commands. E.g. create a customer. However... say if I have two micro services, e.g. a order micro service and an shipping micro service, how does the shipping micro service get the events published from the order micro service. Specifically, how does those customer events, translate to commands for the shipping service.

So let's take a simple example of: - Command created from the order's API to place an order. - A OrderPlacedEvent is published to the event store. How does the shipping service listen and react to this is it need to then DispatchOrder and create ain turn an OrderDispatchedEvent.

Does the write side of the shipping microservice then need to poll or also have a catch up subscription to the order stream? If so how does an event get translated to an command using DDD approach?

Answer (score 2):

> something like a catch up subscription can be used to subscribe to a stream to receive any events written to it

Yes, using catch-up subscriptions is the right way of doing it. You need to keep the stream position of your subscription persisted somewhere as well.

[Here](https://github.com/PacktPublishing/Hands-On-Domain-Driven-Design-with-.NET-Core/blob/master/Chapter11/in-database/Marketplace/Infrastructure/ProjectionManager.cs) you can find some sample code that works. I am not posting the whole snippet since it is too long.

The projection service startup flow is:

- Load the checkpoint (first time ever it would be the stream start)
- Subscribe to the stream from that checkpoint

The runtime flow will then be:

- The subscription will then call the function you provide when it receives an event. There's some plumbing there to do, like if you subscribe to `$all`, you need to filter out system events (it will be easier in the next version of Event Store)
- Project the event
- Store the new checkpoint

If you make your projections idempotent, you can store the checkpoint from time to time and save some IO.

> how does the shipping micro service get the events published from the order micro service

When you build a brand new system and you have a small team working on all the components, you can make a shortcut and subscribe to domain events from another service, as you'd do with projections. Within the integration context (between the boxes), ordering should not be important so you can use persistent subscriptions so you won't need to think about checkpoints. Event Store will do it for you.

Be aware that it introduces tight coupling on the domain event schema of the originating service. Your contexts will have the Partnership relationship or the downstream service will be a Conformist.

When you move forward with your system, you might decide to decouple those contexts properly. So, you introduce a stable event API for the service that publishes events for others to consume. The same subscription that you used for integration can now instead take care of translating domain (internal) events to integration (external) events. The consuming context would then use the stable API and the domain model of the upstream service will be free in iterating on their domain model, as soon as they keep the conversion up-to-date.

It won't be necessary to use Event Store for the downstream context, they could just as well use a message broker. Integration events usually don't need to be persisted due to their transient nature.

We are running a webinar series about Event Sourcing at Event Store, check our web site to get on-demand access to previous webinars and you might find interesting to join future ones.

Answer (score 1):

> The difficulty I'm having is the communication & a handling events from service-to-service (both from a write to read service and between micro services).

The difficulty is not your fault - the DDD literature is really weak when it comes to discussing the plumbing.

Greg Young discusses some of the issues of subscription in the latter part of his [Polygot Data](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hv2dKtPq0ME) talk.

[Eventide Project](http://docs.eventide-project.org/) has documentation that does a decent job of explaining the principles behind how the plumbing fits things together.

> Between micro services, I am having an even harder time...

The basic idea: your message store is fundamentally a *database*; when the host of your microservice wakes up, it queries the message store for messages after some checkpoint, and then feeds them to your domain logic (updating its own local copy of the checkpoint as needed).

So the host pulls a document with events in it from the store, and transforms that document into a stream of `handle(Event)` commands that ultimately get passed to your domain component.

Put another way, you build a host that polls the database for information, parses the response, and then passes the parsed data to the domain model, and writes its own checkpoints.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Still not 100% certain on everything. I have seen that talk before but I had a re-watch and might understand a little. So correct me if i'm wrong:
You don't want to use subscriptions on the read side, because each model/projection should poll the event store itself and handle its own checkpoint. This allows you to wipe individual models each separately, wiping one if needed, scaling them and if one went down, it can catch up independently.
Its a little bit of a mind shift if correct, cause always tried to avoid polling, but here it is appropriate and benficial

Comment: Still confused about events between micro services though. Is the word "document" used here deliberately. I seem to read it as it does the same thing and will poll the event store for new events. keeping a checkpoint, just like the read site of the event's source micro service.
I would understand if a second micro service would have to poll the event store in the same way and keep the check point. but how does that work with scaling? would the checkpoint instead be a global one for that type of service? and would it have to be persisted without ever being wiped?

Comment: i don't know if that last comment made complete sense. The current way I picture a micro-service reacting to events (event read which triggers business logic) as happening on the microservices write side, as its the one that holds the business logic.
So do both the reading of events for the write and read the same (they both poll), but instead of the write being able to wipe its checkpoint (like the read side projections), it has to keep onto it so it knows never to handle an event twice (potentially making duplicates of its own events)

Comment: "DDD literature is really weak when it comes to discussing the plumbing" - that's why I wrote the book, right? :)